# PHP MySql: SUM table value Where="from-other-table"? (INNER JOIN)

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

There is 2 table: "users" and "clicks".

Users have: 'username' and 'referrer'
Clicks have: 'user' and 'value'

users.username = clicks.user

How can I SUM clicks.value of the users whos referrer is "janosuser"?

I know it's INNER Join but I don't know what is the sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are not sure whether the username in users table is unique or not

```
SELECT sum(clicks.value) 
   FROM clicks 
   WHERE clicks.user IN 
       (SELECT users.username from users WHERE users.referrer = "janosuser")
```

Or

When you are sure that  users table doesn't have repeated username, i.e. username is unique in the users table, otherwise for that users there will be repeated rows and sum will be inflated

```
SELECT SUM(clicks.value) 
    FROM clicks 
        INNER JOIN 
    users 
    ON users.username = clicks.user 
    where users.refere = "janosuser"
```

Comment: I get this message: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: in the INNER JOIN method? try adding 'COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci' after where users.referer = "Janosuser"

Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(clicks.value) FROM clicks INNER JOIN users ON users.username = clicks.user WHERE users.referrer = 'janosuser'
```

Comment: I got this message: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: `ALTER TABLE users CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`
`ALTER TABLE clicks CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`