# Rails ActionView::Template::Error: Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

**NOTE:** The Generic SQL answer is [Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074)

This question is specific to rails/active-record, when you have:

> ActionView::Template::Error: Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770234/1536309) says to `COLLATE` but I was hoping for some examples specific to rails.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem and wanted to document

Before:

```
Membership.joins(person: :account).where(foo: :bar)
```

it was showing I had some collation mismatches and needed to update.

After:

```
Membership
.joins('INNER JOIN `people` ON `people`.`id` = `memberships`.`person_id`')
.joins('INNER JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`person_id` COLLATE utf8_general_ci = `people`.`id` COLLATE utf8_general_ci')
```

More specifically you add `COLLATE <UTF8_BLAH>` after your column names.

instead of:

```
joins accounts on person_id = people.id
```

use:

```
joins accounts on person_id COLLATE utf8_general_ci = people.id COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

you can also solve this problem by fixing the collation for all your tables and your entire database.