# MYSQL ERROR while searching Hindi Content

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting below error while searching `hindi` content from table

> Database query failedIllegal mix of collations
>   (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for
>   operation 'like'

This is my query

```
SELECT COUNT(art.id) as num FROM lehren_articles art INNER JOIN 
lehren_category_master cat ON art.category_id=cat.id INNER JOIN 
lehren_sub_category subcat ON art.subcategory_id=subcat.id INNER JOIN 
lehren_main_menu menu ON art.menu_id=menu.id INNER JOIN lehren_authors auth 
ON art.author_id=auth.id where art.id<>''  and ((cat.name LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  
%' OR art.title LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' OR art.id LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' OR 
art.created LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' OR menu.menu_name LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' 
OR subcat.name LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' OR auth.name LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' OR 
art.display_cube LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' OR art.language LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  
%' OR art.bucket LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' OR art.status LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %' 
OR art.modified_date LIKE '%क्या रीमा लागू  %'))
```

Comment: `FROM lehren_articles art INNER / lehren_category_master cat` you have spaces in your query ?

Comment: check this [Illegal mix of collations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic)

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your collation on your database and table.

```
SET collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'
```

then for your databases

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

ALTER TABLE your_table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

MySql was developed by Swedish developers so thats why the default collation is set to swedish.

Have a look at this link too for more details -> https://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations/