# How to fix "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'"?

Tags: mysql

Currently I am working on a project where I am working on the library lending system openbiblio where I would like to work with umlauts, but I am getting the following error:

> Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'

[image: Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal mix of collations (utf8\_unicode\_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8\_general\_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770074/illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-unicode-ci-implicit-and-utf8-general-ci-implic)

Comment: How can i change the Entity from utf8 to iso8859-1? 
It would be difficult to modiefy the Database because some functions Needs iso885-1 to work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, changed the encoding to UTF-8 in the database