# How to fix "Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='"

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, collation

While executing a stored procedure in MySQL on my remove server as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `SetNextPage`(
    IN `inRefNo` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    IN `inStage` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    IN `inRedirectTo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
    IN `inSurveyType` varchar(14) COLLATE utf8_general_ci
)
BEGIN
    IF inSurveyType = 'preinspection' THEN
        UPDATE preinspections SET Stage = inStage, RedirectTo = inRedirectTo WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
    ELSE
        UPDATE surveys SET Stage = inStage, RedirectTo = inRedirectTo WHERE RefNo = inRefNo;
    END IF;
END
```

I am receiving error message as:

**Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='**

Here's a screenshot of tables in my database with query as below:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="mydatabase" AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE";
```

[image: Screenshot of tables from phpMyAdmin]

*This table **quick_tables.bck** is just stuck in there because of .bck in its name. But it is not being anywhere in my code.*

Here's the snapshot of system variables with an SQL query as below:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE ("character%") OR Variable_name LIKE ("Collation%");
```

Variable_name               **Value**
character_set_client        **utf8**
character_set_connection    **utf8**
character_set_database      **utf8**
character_set_filesystem    **binary**
character_set_results       **utf8**
character_set_server        **latin1**
character_set_system        **utf8**
character_sets_dir          **/usr/share/mysql/charsets/**
collation_connection        **utf8_unicode_ci**
collation_database          **utf8_general_ci**
collation_server            **latin1_swedish_ci**

**Being on remote server with Shared Hosting, I cannot change environmental variables.**

What changes should I make to make my stored procedure to run?

Comment: check my post for this problem. maybe it will work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71659466/4335210

Answer (score 1):

Do `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE SetNextPage \G`

You will probably find that the character set and/or collation in effect when you defined the proc was not what you want now.

Either change the collation of your connection, or drop the proc, SET NAMES, and re-CREATE the proc.

For general use, utf8_genera_ci is the least 'good', followed by utf8_unicode_ci, then utf8_unicode_520_ci.  There is an even better one when you get to MySQL 8.0.

You *can* change the *SESSION* variables for your connection.

Since there is a difference between the settings in the Proc and the connection, one or the other needs changing.

To change the proc, `DROP` it, `SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_520_ci;` re-`CREATE` it.

To change the connection, see what the API provides in the connection.  Or do a SET like above.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have done `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE SetNextPage`. Here is the required output as [key: value pairs] - [Procedure: *SetNextPage*], [character_set_client: *utf8mb4*], [collation_connection: *utf8mb4_general_ci*], [Database Collation: *latin1_general_ci*] on hosting server. The value of collation_connection is different from the one as given by query `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE ("character%")` as shown above.  Any problems with this? If yes, where and how to fix it?

Comment: My hosting company has blocked my hosting account while trying to fix collation issues in database connection and tables :(.

Comment: Changing the connection collation and other collations worked.

Answer (score 0):

Following script in MySQL worked for me and most probably is going to work for everyone.

```
/* Set collations of system variables */
SET @@collation_connection = UTF8MB4_GENERAL_CI;
SET @@collation_database = UTF8MB4_GENERAL_CI;
SET @@collation_server = UTF8MB4_GENERAL_CI;

/* Set collations of database tables */
ALTER TABLE table1 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE table2 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
and so on...
```

Also change/set CHARACTER SET of all eligible variables to `utf8mb4` as I have done in my script like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `SetNextPage`(
IN `inRefNo` varchar(30) CHARSET utf8mb4,
IN `inStage` varchar(40) CHARSET utf8mb4,
.....
```

You can choose any collation and corresponding character set you like but they should be matching where ever used.

If things might somehow with different collations/character sets, I have no idea about that.